# Emacs: C-a not working

Tags: emacs

I'm using Emacs 22.3.1 on windows.
C-a is not working. (Left Control-A is working, Right Control-A is not working)
I even set : (global-set-key (kbd "C-a") 'beginning-of-line). still not working.

Any idea?

Comment: Do right ctrl-c & ctrl-v work for copy&paste outside of Emacs? Perhaps the problem is in your keyboard configuration.

Comment: Did you try with an empty .emacs/.emacs.el?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was wrong?

Comment: i think problem is not with emacs, it is something wrong with my usb keyboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do a

```
M-x describe-key
```

and press C-a to check what it is bound to.

(this will at least indicate that emacs understands C-a in some form)

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem on Windows. If m-x describe key is normal, the problem may be that "other programs" occupy this shortcut key. For me, the reason is that Microsoft Pinyin input method switches between Chinese and English.